# How could I get store code from URL?

Tags: multistore

How could I get the store code from URL?

For example, I would like to get "es" and "en" from these urls:

*mystore.com/es*
*mystore.com/en*

Using

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()
```

is not a possibility.

EDIT:
By the moment I'm using this function:

```
$segments = explode('/', trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/'));  
$allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();  
foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId => $val)  
    $_stores[] = Mage::app()->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getCode();

if (in_array($segments[0], $_stores)) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Joseantgv, This type f url are coming when `Add Store Code to Urls`[**system>configuration>general>Web**] setting enable from admin.

```
mystore.com/es
mystore.com/en
```

According to setting  the store code  to BaseUrl.

You can get this by using string  replace.

Can check setting by `Mage::getStoreConfig('web/url/use_store')`

and for getting current store code try this

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()
```

Store url with store code.

**Mage::getUrl() with store code.**

Comment: Thanks! I asked if there is any Magento function to get this code without having to split url and comparing between all store codes